# How to change the root directory for my domain in kloxo?

Tags: directory, root

I want to change my root directory for my domain. My root directory is `/home/mrdownloader.com/`
but I want change it to `/home/mrdownloader/`

Comment: Its a question for http://serverfault.com

Comment: You might need to edit, `/etc/httpd/conf/kloxo/default.conf`

Answer (score 0):

just click Domains in the left tree -> click globe below (Domain for xxx.tld) --> Document Root --> change the folder, that's it